# BigQuery dataset access using Google Group for service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-iam

I have a BigQuery dataset which I would like to share with a group of people using a Google Group.

I added a Google Group as BigQuery Data Viewer and for personal accounts in that group this works fine.

However, when I add a service account to the group using its email, it gets access denied.

Is it possible to grant access to BQ datasets for service accounts using Google Groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works correctly - just make sure you use the option `Direct add members` rather than `Invite members`, which sends users an email and waits for a confirmation, which obviously won't work for a service account.

Note, if there is an invite pending, it needs to be revoked before adding a member directly for it to be effective.